# Export column value to another task SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have 1 .csv file that I import. Because of the layout of the file I need to import it again to get a certain value that needs to be used for the next Data Flow task that will use that value for every row.

Below is an example of the file:

[image]

I need **STATEMENT DATE** for all records.

This is how the package looks like:

[image]

Inside **Get Statement Date** task I have the following *Data Flow*:

[image]

I don't really want to export the column I just want it to go into a variable that I can use in the next task And I am not sure were this should be done.

I am still learning how SSIS works.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a script component as Destination and assign that column to your variable.

Keep in mind the variable Datatype should be compatible.

Declare a variable in class ScriptMain to store your value:

```
public DateTime t;
```

On Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row):

```
t = Row.StatementDate;
```

On PostExecute:

```
Variables.teste = t;
```

It will assign it the number of rows you actually have.(it's not a problem since you are only retrieving one row I guess). Only the last row will actually be saved to your variable.

Comment: Something like:     Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)

Comment: Also don't Forget to add your variable to the ReadWriteVariables on the Custom Option of the task(same tab as edit script).

Comment: I get error that Dts does not exist in current context. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just found that solution. Thanks

Comment: I get the following error:
The collection of variables locked for read and write access is not available outside of PostExecute.

Comment: Sir, you are a scholar and a gentlemen. Thanks it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Use **RecordSet Destination**. This can be used to store temporary results which will be stored in a variable of type object. You can use this along with Foreach loop to process each record. you can refer this link for more info.
[RecordSet Destination](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879316.aspx)